# React,js bad syntax 400 request bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, post, request

I am trying to send a Post request to my API in react, but I am receiving bad syntax error. I referred to this Post on StackOverflow, but I do not see the difference with my code.

[React.js, how to send a multipart/form-data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610811/react-js-how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-to-server)

```
export default class CapsuleForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userUrl: this.props.auth.domain + "/users/" + this.props.userID,
      dateToPost: moment(),
      image: "",
      caption: "",
      redirect: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = new FormData()
    form.append("user", this.state.userUrl);
    form.append("dateToPost", this.state.dateToPost.format());
    form.append("image", this.state.image.files[0]);
    form.append("caption", this.state.caption);

    for (var pair of form.entries()) {
       console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
    }

    this.props.auth.postCapsule(
      form
    ).then(() => {
       this.setState({redirect: true})
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        alert(err);
    })
  }

  handleDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      dateToPost: date
    });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState(
         {
             caption: e.target.value
         }
     )
  }

  render() {
    function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
      return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
          <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <h1> Create a SnapCapusle </h1>
        {/* TODO Find out why FieldGroup component does not pass onChange function
         correctly */}
        <ControlLabel> Date </ControlLabel>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.dateToPost}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          style={ css }
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat="LLL"
        />
        <FormGroup id="1">
          <ControlLabel> File </ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="file"
            label="Image"
            name="image"
            inputRef={ref => {
              this.state.image = ref;
            }}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup id="2">
          <ControlLabel> Caption </ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter text"
            name="caption"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <Button type="submit"> Submit </Button>
        </FormGroup>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the PostCapsule function.

```
postCapsule(formData) {
      console.log("PostCapsule called to " + `${this.domain}/snapcapsule/`)
      return fetch(`${this.domain}/snapcapsule/`, {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          body: formData
      })
    }
```

Here is what a successful Post Request on my server looks like
[image: successful Post request]

Here is what the javascript code printed to the console.
[image: Browser log of of data being sent server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by looking into http error in the console. If you go to network tab, you can click on the request and it will give you a error message. The error message told me no url match the one I was giving it. I realized I forgot to end the userURL with a "/".

[image]

```
this.state = {
    userUrl: this.props.auth.domain + "/users/" + this.props.userID + "/",
    dateToPost: moment(),
    image: "",
    caption: "",
    redirect: false
};
```