# Unable to make post call and send file via html form in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, spring-boot

I'm new in reactjs and tried hard to find my answer but I still have the same problem. I've checked all same questions and answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610811/react-js-how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-to-server), but non of them helped me so if you know any same Q&A please let me know.

I have a html form which suppose to accept one zip file and one string then  want to pass them to the Web service via Post method.

I have the rest api server which I've written by Spring boot and now try to make a client test project for test it. The test by Postman is successful and I send the request and receive the response without issues, but with this API I was unsuccessful. I've changed a lot in my app through what I learnt from internet resources and this is the last step I got stuck

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to find the bug.

this is my ReactJs code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import img from "./images/test.jpg"
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 

class DoPost extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            id:null,
            fileData:null,
            url:"http://localhost:8990/getId"
        };
    }





    handleSubmit(event) {

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fId', this.fId.value);
        formData.append('inputPackage', this.inputPackage.value); 
        console.log(this.fId.value);
        console.log(this.inputPackage.value);
        fetch(this.state.url, { 
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(res => {
            alert(res);
        });


    }



    render() {

        return (<div>
                <section className="login-block">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4 login-sec">
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <label htmlFor="fId">fId Id:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fId" id="fId" ref={el => this.fId = el} /><br/><br/>
                                     <div className="form-group files color">
                                        <label>Upload Your File </label>
                                        <input type="file" name="inputPackage" ref={el => this.inputPackage = el}  required
                                                className="file-controller"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="align-center">
                                        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-info " value="Send the request" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-8 banner-sec">
                                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                        <div className="carousel-item">
                                            <img className="d-block img-fluid" src={img} alt="First slide"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DoPost;
```

Comment: You already had a good suggestion from @devserkan but could you add the result of the `alert(res)` or even better replace the `alert` by a `console.log` and post the log of what happens during the submit. It will also help other users who may encounter the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @remix23, I've put console.log but first of all my problem is there is no actions after it reach to "fetch" part. it even not stop in breakpoints ( I'm using Webstorm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the error you get here but your `fetch` is somehow wrong. First response from `fetch` is a promise and you need to handle it.

```
fetch(this.state.url, { 
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
         .then( res => res.json())
         .then( res => {
            alert(res);
        })
);
```

Also, you need to add `event.preventDefault()` in your `handleSubmit` method to prevent refreshing after form submission.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @devserkan, The problem is when I run the api, it shows the data received from form (id and file path) but after that it does nothing and the page is refresh only, also the data goes to the url as like as GET method!!!

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in the first line of your `handleSubmit` method and let see what will happen.

Comment: in this situation which I tested as well. it shows the value of id and file path from ref but before fetch when I check the "formData" it is empty!! it means it send nothing to API

Comment: How do you check your formData? You can't see directly logging formData values. You need to use `formData.getAll("fId")` to get all the values of `fId` for example.

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, try to use the state instead of refs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried JSON.stringify(formData) which was empty but with formData.getAll("fId") it shows me the value. So why my server not receive any data??!! 
I tried the state but I needed to keep the value before press submit button when I set state for file or text input, the submit function loaded without calling, I didn't figure out where was my problem. That's why I use ref. I would be grateful if you could give me any example ( or link ) to show me how I can use state in this situation which should wait for submit button.

Comment: Well, I don't know any direct link buy you can define a `handleChange` method and this method updates your state properties that match with your inputs. After that, your `handleSubmit` method would create the `formData` then post it. For the current situation, can you change the `body` in the `fetch` method like that: `body: JSON.stringify(formData)`

Comment: Thanks again, I've checked the server and realized the id goes correctly but the multipartFile is empty. I made change as JSON for body but as I expected the server reject the request as "Current request is not a multipart request"

Comment: So, as a noob this is it for me :) I've only tried uploading some files once a while ago and forgot lots of it :D So, is `req.files` is empty on your backend? Though this can change according to the upload library or code probably.

Comment: I'm using Spring boot in backend.
`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getName")
    @ResponseBody
    String Response(@RequestParam("inputPackage") MultipartFile[] inputPackages, @RequestParam("FId") String id) {`

and in this situation it shows me the correct Fid but the size of inputPackages is 0

I don't know is that helpful?

Comment: Well, not helpful for me :) I've used Express and NodeJS and as I said I forgot most of it. But, can you see the file path if you use `formData.getAll("inputPackage")`?

Comment: Thanks anyway, you have been helpful and I appreciate. 
the path shows me is : **C:\\fakepath\\test.zip** (which is not correct path, the correct path should be : **"C:\\data\\test.zip"**)

Comment: Ok, it shows me the same when I try here and I don't use even Windows :) So, it must be a fake path, but the file name is right I guess. Sorry, I can't help any further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. is there any way to give you point for your attempt? I got stuck and straggling. I made the other more complete question from both server side and client side may be some one could help me for both side.

Comment: You are welcome. If you mean point for SO, you can upvote my answer without accepting it :) I hope you solve your issue.

Comment: I tried but because I'm new here it didn't accept it. Sorry!

Comment: No problem with that, but it is easy actually. Just click the "up arrow" beside my answer :)

Comment: Yeah I tried that one. but it gave me the warning that because your reputation is less that 15 your vote not include or something like this...
how can I improve my reputation?

Comment: Oh, ok no problem then. I totally forgot the reputation limit :) You can improve it by asking good questions or providing good answers.