# Sending multipart/form-data with authorization header from react

Tags: reactjs, go, authorization, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a POST request with form data from a React frontend to a Go backend.

```
const upload = () => {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);
        data.append('namespace', namespace);
        const requestOptions = {
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'basic ' + props.getToken() },
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        };
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/upload`, requestOptions)
            .then(
                response => alert(response.status)
            ).catch(
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    };
```

On the backend side, I am trying to access the data the following way:

```
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Read content
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    file, fileHeader, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fileHeader)
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, file)
    yamlData := buf.Bytes()
    namespace := r.FormValue("namespace")
    ...
}
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data
```

Also, the fileHeader is `nil`.

The only possible solution I found was to remove the header as mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610811/react-js-how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-to-server), but encoding the authorization token in the POST body is of course not my preferred way of fixing this issue.

As the question was asked already and I wasn't clear about this one:
Setting the headers to

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'basic ' + props.getToken() }
```

leads to the same problem.

PS:
React fetch seems to automatically generate a header such as the following:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykm4IEyyauWp42XvA
```

When setting another header manually, the fetch API does not apply this header. A potential solution might be to combine the headers, however I have no idea how this could work.

PPS: Trying the same with `axios` leads to the same issue.

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/upload`,
    data: data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'basic ' + props.getToken() }
    })
        .then(
            response => alert(response.status)
        ).catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        );
```

Comment: So, why don't you just set the Content-Type header?

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Peter. Unfortunately, setting the header ```headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'basic ' + props.getToken() }``` leads to exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `mode: "no-cors"` to your `requestOptions` will help.
There's something odd with this library I couldn't figured out and it's that even sending explicitly the `Authorization` header I can't see it in the backend, so you might need an extra configuration to be sure that header is sent.

I tested the back end and that definitely works as expected (tested with Postman sending `Content-Type`: `multipart/form-data` and an attached file

Comment: Thank you for your help, Andres. I can reproduce the behavior as the Authorization header is not sent to the backend in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: The [Fetch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) states that `mode: "no-cors"` does not allow `Authorization` headers.

Comment: What I saw is if leaving `mode` as default (`cors`) won't send automatically the `Content-type` header which forces you to send explicitly the `Content-Type` header making sure you send an appropriate `boundary`. (Something like: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="a boundary"`)
I have tried different combinations to achieve the behaviour you want, but no luck