# How to send an image to the backend using React Native and PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

I have developed a website using React and PHP. Currently, I am in the process of creating a React Native application that is similar to the website. For this purpose, I am using the same PHP for both the website and the application. React Native is still new to me, and I am stuck at a certain point. I would like to know how to send an image to the backend so that the backend can store the image and send the information to the database. Currently, when I send a new product, it says :

string(175) "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/30108c4a-2441-442f-aef3-87ce5be33537.jpeg"

**Warning**:  mime_content_type(file: ///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/30108c4a-2441-442f-aef3-87ce5be33537.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/html/controllers/foodController.php** on line **31**

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(file: ///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/30108c4a-2441-442f-aef3-87ce5be33537.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/html/controllers/foodController.php** on line **34**
{
"message": "Produit ajouté avec succès."
}

Frontend :

file ApiService :

```
       addFood: async (foodData) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/foods/add`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: foodData
            });

            const responseData = await response.json();
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(responseData.message || `HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return responseData;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    },
```

File where the upload form is located:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { apiService } from "../API/ApiService";
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import img from "../../assets/logo.png"


function FormAddProduct() {
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
        imageURI: null,
        category: "",
    });

    const [categorys, setCategorys] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCategories = async () => {
            try {
                const fetchedCategories = await apiService.getAllCategories();
                setCategorys(fetchedCategories);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération des catégories:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchCategories();
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('title', productData.title);
            formData.append('description', productData.description);
            formData.append('category', productData.category);
            formData.append('price', productData.price);
            formData.append('image', {
                uri: productData.imageURI,
                type: "image/jpg",
                name: `product-image-${Date.now()}.jpg`,
            });

            console.log("uri", productData.imageURI);

            const result = await apiService.addFood(formData);
            alert('Plat ajouté avec succès!');
            resetForm();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Une erreur est survenue lors de l\'ajout du plat.');
        }
    };


    const resetForm = () => {
        setProductData({
            title: "",
            description: "",
            price: "",
            imageURI: null,
            category: "",
        });
    };

    const handlePriceChange = (inputValue) => {
        const convertedValue = inputValue.replace(',', '.');
        const regex = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
    
        if (regex.test(convertedValue) || convertedValue === '') {
            setProductData({ ...productData, price: convertedValue });
        }
    };

    const handleImageChange = async (result) => {
        if (result && result.uri) {
            try {
                setProductData({ ...productData, imageURI: result.uri }); // Stocker l'URI dans productData.imageURI
                console.log('reussi', productData.imageURI); // Afficher productData.imageURI dans le console.log
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la manipulation de l\'image:', error);
                setProductData({ ...productData, imageURI: null });
            }
        } else {
            setProductData({ ...productData, imageURI: null });
        }
    };
    

    const pickFile = async () => {
        const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (!permissionResult.granted) {
            alert('Permission refusée pour accéder aux fichiers.');
            return;
        }
      
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 1,
        });
    
        if (!result.cancelled && result.assets.length > 0) {
            handleImageChange(result.assets[0]); // Pass the first asset object
        }
    };
    

    
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.containerScrollAddProduct}>
            <View style={styles.containerFormAddProduct}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputAddProduct}
                    placeholder="Nom du produit"
                    value={productData.title}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setProductData({ ...productData, title: text })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputAddProduct}
                    placeholder="Description"
                    value={productData.description}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setProductData({ ...productData, description: text })}
                />
                <View style={styles.containerSelectAddForm}>
                    <RNPickerSelect
                        items={categorys.map(category => ({ label: category.name, value: category.name }))}
                        onValueChange={(value) => setProductData({ ...productData, category: value })}
                        style={{ inputIOS: styles.picker, inputAndroid: styles.picker }}
                        useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
                        Icon={() => {
                            return <Ionicons name="chevron-down" margin={11} size={30} color="#FF9A00" />;
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputAddProduct}
                    placeholder="Prix"
                    value={productData.price}
                    onChangeText={handlePriceChange}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonImageAddProduct} onPress={pickFile}><Text style={styles.textAddImage}>Choisir une image</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonAddProduct} onPress={handleSubmit}><Text style={styles.textAddProduct}>Ajouter</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.card}>
                    <Image source={productData.image && productData.imageURI ? { uri: productData.imageURI } : img} style={styles.imageCard}/>
                        <Text style={styles.textCard}>{productData.title}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.containerBottomCard}>
                            <Text style={styles.priceCard}>{productData.price} €</Text>
                            <View style={styles.containerButtonCard}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCard}><Text style={styles.textButtonCard}>+</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Backend :

```
public function uploadImageFromReactNative($imageURI)
{
    $dossierDestination = "images/"; 

    
    $imagePath = parse_url($imageURI, PHP_URL_PATH);

    
    $nomFichier = basename($imagePath);

    
    $imageContent = file_get_contents($imagePath);

    
    $nomUnique = uniqid() . "." . pathinfo($nomFichier, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    
    file_put_contents($dossierDestination . $nomUnique, $imageContent);

    return $nomUnique;
}





public function addFood()
{

  if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['price'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      var_dump('if ',$_FILES['image']);
      $imageFile = $_FILES['image'];
      $imagePath = 'images/' . basename($imageFile['name']);
      move_uploaded_file($imageFile['tmp_name'], $imagePath);
    } elseif (isset($_POST['imageURI'])) {
      var_dump('elseif ',$_POST['imageURI']);
      $imagePath = $this->uploadImageFromReactNative($_POST['imageURI']); 
    } else {
      http_response_code(400); 
      var_dump('elseimageUir ', $_POST['imageURI']);
      var_dump('else image ', $_FILES['image']);
      
      echo json_encode(array("message" => "Image manquante."));
      return;
    }

    if ($this->model->addFood($title, $description, $category, $price, $imagePath)) {
      
      http_response_code(201); // Code de succès pour création
      echo json_encode(array("message" => "Produit ajouté avec succès."));
    } else {
      
      http_response_code(500); // Erreur interne du serveur
      echo json_encode(array("message" => "Impossible d'ajouter le produit."));
    }
  } else {
    http_response_code(400); 
    $missingFields = [];
    if (!isset($_POST['title'])) {
      $missingFields[] = 'title';
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['description'])) {
      $missingFields[] = 'description';
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['category'])) {
      $missingFields[] = 'category';
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['price'])) {
      $missingFields[] = 'price';
    }
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Données manquantes. Veuillez fournir les champs suivants : " . implode(', ', $missingFields)));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to perform an HTTP file upload, then the Content-Type must not be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but `multipart/form-data`

Comment: And how you are building your `formattedData`, creating key=value pairs separated with `&` - that is also not going to work, for a multipart request. Check [React.js, how to send a multipart/form-data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41610811/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe I had initially tried with multipart/form-data, but each time it gave me the error: "Missing Image". That's why I tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which allowed the backend to receive the image. However, maybe I used multipart/form-data incorrectly. I have just modified the code so that you can see what I did with formData.

Comment: _"That's why I tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which allowed the backend to receive the image."_ - not sure what you mean by that. PHP will absolutely not populate $_FILES with anything, when you send application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Remove the `Content-Type` header from your `fetch` options altogether. This header needs to include the boundary value, that is used to separate the request body parts from each other. fetch will set this header by itself, _correctly_, when you pass a formdata instance that contains file uploads. If you set it yourself like this, then it is likely the boundary value won't get added at all.

Comment: @CBroe Like this? If so, I still receive the error: "Missing Image"  : /

Comment: Oh, I didn't see before, that you are trying to handle the upload from react differently, on the server side. If you are not trying to send the image data so that it will be received in $_POST now, but actually via $_FILES - then please do a var_dump of $_FILES and check what it contains. I can't tell exactly what you are doing there with the image on the client side, but I am guessing that `uri: productData.imageURI` is probably some sort of data URI now, not sure if that submits correctly.

Comment: @CBroe 
Here's what productData.imageURI contains: `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/d6231205-0d36-4dd3-9e65-36efd14172c9.jpeg`

Comment: @CBroe 
I've put var_dumps everywhere to see where my image is arriving, and it's arriving in the elseif, where I then have this error:

Comment: @CBroe 
`string(175) "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/d6231205-0d36-4dd3-9e65-36efd14172c9.jpeg"
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAppWok-db71a03d-1bff-412f-b36b-6ba8c457a16b/ImagePicker/d6231205-0d36-4dd3-9e65-36efd14172c9.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/var/www/html/controllers/foodController.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
{
    "message": "Produit ajouté avec succès."
}`

Comment: A `file:///` URL refers to the local file system. Your PHP code now tries to access a path, that only exists on the client.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You either need to make your react code perform a _real_ file upload, or send the file _content_ as a POST parameter.